# Parse cloud code multiple queries that rely on each other

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am trying to run some cloud functions on parse but the `originalFavorited.first` is not being ran.

```
var _ = require('underscore');
Parse.Cloud.define("userFeed", function (request, response) {
    if (request.user == undefined) {
        response.error("User must be logged in!");
    }

    var friendsQuery = new Parse.Query("Friend");
    friendsQuery.equalTo("fromUser", request.user);

    var badPhotosQuery = new Parse.Query("Photo");
    badPhotosQuery.greaterThanOrEqualTo("flagCount", 3);

    var userFlaggedQuery = new Parse.Query("Photo");
    userFlaggedQuery.containedIn("flagCount", request.user.flaggedItems);

    var allBadPhotosQuery = new Parse.Query.or(badPhotosQuery, userFlaggedQuery);

    var activitiesQuery = new Parse.Query("Activity");
    activitiesQuery.skip(request.params.startRecord);
    activitiesQuery.limit(request.params.numberRecords);
    activitiesQuery.equalTo("type", "favorite");
    activitiesQuery.matchesKeyInQuery("fromUser", "toUser", friendsQuery);
    activitiesQuery.descending("createdAt");
    activitiesQuery.include("photo")
    activitiesQuery.include("fromUser");
    activitiesQuery.notEqualTo("fromUser", request.user);
    activitiesQuery.doesNotMatchQuery("photo", allBadPhotosQuery);


    var parsedResults = [];
    activitiesQuery.find().then(function (results) {
        return results;
    }).then(function (results) {

        var promise = Parse.Promise.as();

        _.each(results, function (activity) {
            promise = promise.then(function () {
                console.log("Parsing results for " + activity);
                var originalFavorited = new Parse.Query("Activity");
                originalFavorited.ascending("createdAt");
                console.log(activity.get("photo"));
                originalFavorited.equalTo("photo", activity.get("photo"));
                originalFavorited.include("photo");
                originalFavorited.include("fromUser");
                originalFavorited.equalTo("type", "favorite");

                originalFavorited.first(function (origResult) {

                    console.log("Found original");
                    parsedResults.push(origResult);
                    return parsedResults;
                });
            });
        });
        return promise;
    }).then(function () {
        var filteredResults = _.uniq(parsedResults, false);
        response.success(filteredResults);
    });
```

For my output `console.log (activity.get("photo"));` is outputting the object. `photo` is a Pointer to my `Photo` class.

Am I doing the promises properly so that the code is being ran synchronously?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var parsedResults = [];
activitiesQuery.find().then(function (results) {

    /// ---- REMOVED HERE ----
    // return results;
    //    }).then(function (results) {

    var promise = Parse.Promise.as();

    _.each(results, function (activity) {
        promise = promise.then(function () {
            console.log("Parsing results for " + activity);
            var originalFavorited = new Parse.Query("Activity");
            originalFavorited.ascending("createdAt");
            console.log(activity.get("photo"));
            originalFavorited.equalTo("photo", activity.get("photo"));
            // the two line belows can be ignored since you have the same value in activity.get("photo") and activity.get("fromUser"), included previously
            originalFavorited.include("photo");
            originalFavorited.include("fromUser");
            originalFavorited.equalTo("type", "favorite");

            /// ---- ADDED LINE BELOW ----
            originalFavorited.limit(1);
            originalFavorited.find(function (subResults) {

                console.log("Found original");

                /// ADDED CHECK HERE 
                if (subResults.length > 0){
                    parsedResults.push(subResults[0]);
                }

                /// ---- CHANGED HERE ----
                var subPromise = Parse.Promise.as();
                subPromise.resolve(parsedResults);
                return subPromise ; // returning a promise to promise series

            /// ---- ADDED ERROR HANDLING HERE ----
            },function(error){

                console.log("Unable to retrieve first element in originalFavorited query. Cause: " + error.message);
                var errPromise = Parse.Promise.as();
                errPromise.reject(error);
                return errPromise; // return failed promise to promise series just for continue the operation series up to the end
            });
        });
    });

    return promise;

},function(error){  /// ---- ADDED ERROR HANDLING HERE ----

    console.log("Unable to perform find on activitiesQuery : " + error.message);
    response.error(error.message);

}).then(function () {
    var filteredResults = _.uniq(parsedResults, false);
    response.success(filteredResults);
});
```

**Note**: don't forget the parse limit execution of custom functions, so choose properly the amount of query to perform for each custom function call

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, unfortunately the `Found original` query doesn't seem to be being ran.

Comment: Have you checked if any error has been occurred for that query? try to handle the error callback also in the .first(...) method. I've updated the answer in that point.

Comment: There is no error in the error log with the updated code

Comment: Mmm, strange. Just another test you can do: try to use the find() method instead of first(). I've updated the answer for simplify the test.

Comment: `photo` is a pointer, would that have anything to do with it maybe?

Comment: You can probably avoid to include photo in originalFavorited.include("photo") since you already make it with activitiesQuery.include("photo") (maybe it is a typing error, but in your question you've forgotten to put the semicolon in that line, at activitiesQuery.include("photo") ).

Comment: ps: sorry for the edit, i wanted to edit my answer not your question :/

Comment: changing to the latest you have in your post didn't seem to work either. Maybe you can't do a query inside a query?

Comment: You can made nested query without problem, I made it and i've no problem. Unless your custom function goes in timeout ( as far as i know is over 7 seconds ) i can't understand why it doesn't work...

Comment: You could try to remove all the include() methods in your script, and so see if it works just with the pointers (each .include() is considered as a new parse request i think)

Comment: Anyway, is really needed to perform a promise series? Can you obtain the same result you expected only using the first query activitiesQuery?